# Incorrect validation loop

Tags: applescript, script, automation, color

I made a loop that inserts a number into a string, and by the color of the number (blue - registered, red - missing), using the standard utility Digital Colors Meter determines the color of the number. Then, depending on the color, it either adds a variable with a number from the initial txt file to the new one, or starts the script from the beginning. At least it should be.

But something is going wrong in loop. It checks the color, inserts numbers, everything is fine, but apparently the wrong condition, apparently the wrong data types. It inserts different numbers into the scatter. Some will insert, some will not, regardless of the initial condition. What could be the reason? Where is the error?

```
   tell application "Digital Color Meter" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Digital Color Meter"
            click menu item 1 of menu 1 of menu bar item 4 of menu bar 1
        end tell
        do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c \"import objc;bndl = objc.loadBundle('CoreGraphics', globals(), '/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework');objc.loadBundleFunctions(bndl, globals(), [('CGWarpMouseCursorPosition', 'v{CGPoint=dd}')]);CGWarpMouseCursorPosition((" & 1002 & "," & 222 & "));\""
        set rgbColors to words of (the clipboard)
    end tell
    if rgbColors is equal to {"77", "39", "38"} then
        exit repeat
    else
        do shell script "echo " & quoted form of n & " >> /Users/oneone/Desktop/base2.txt"
    end if
```

Only the color check condition for Digital Color Meter is presented here. Through the do shell, the color is read at the mouse position and the variable is added to the new file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Let’s edit the original question. Reposting is strongly discouraged here. Fixing a closed or older question with edits to refine and clarify works best and gets lots of support / best chance for an answer in my experience

Comment: Since you've taken the resource-intensive step of calling out to a shell to call out to python to bridge to objective-c in order to move the mouse cursor, it might make more sense and be a lot more robust if you wrote the whole thing in PyObjC, which would then allow you to make use of `NSAttributedString` class methods which include being able to detect the colour of text, fonts, etc. Alternatively, python also has access to the Core Graphics framework, which you can use to detect the colour of a pixel under the mouse cursor. Both these methods eliminate a need for _Digital Colour Meter_.